# Предложение односоставное или двусоставное?

Tags: синтаксис

> Ничего не будет дано.

Думаю, предложение нужно отнести к односоставным, т.к "не будет дано" можно заменить на "не дадут".

Comment: Пробелов не должно быть перед знаками препинания, а не наоборот. На точках не экономьте, и вообще, свои тексты перед отправкой надо проверять.

Comment: Непростой вопрос, поэтому закрывать его нежелательно. А вот увидеть ответ хотелось бы.

Comment: Анна,  при замене может уточнить смысл, но так не определяется структура заданного предложения. Существует синтаксическая синонимия, когда одно и то же содержание можно выразить различным образом.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что вы правы, и это действительно **односоставное безличное предложение.**

---

Почему не двусоставное?

1)Если "ничего" было бы подлежащим, то оно бы могло корректно заменяться на "ничто/что" и быть действующим субъектом.
*Что не будет дано? Не будет дано что?* - **ничто** (в.п), это типичный вопрос дополнения.
*Не будет дано чего? -* **ничего.**  (р.п)

2)В данном предложении явно есть лицо, которое не названо,- это мы, или они, или вы, поэтому мы понимаем, что субъекта, исполнителя действия, здесь быть не должно.

***[нами, ими, вами]** ничего не будет дано.*

3)Сказуемое выражено формой глагола-связки "быть" и причастием в форме среднего рода, что типично для безличных предложений:

***Грамота.ру|** Глагол-связка в безличной форме + краткое страдательное причастие:
В комнате ***было** **накурено**.**

---

"Дано" - это очень обтекаемая форма, которая мыслится обособленно, без опоры на субъект действия.

Comment: Доазать, что предложение безличное не так просто. Ведь нужно точно определить его вид, так как среди безличных встречаются разные конструкции.  Дело в том, что  соотносительное утвердительное предложение является ДВУСОСТАВНЫМ. Это дано.  Это будет дано. Что дано? Что еще будет дано. Переходим к отрицанию: Ничего не будет дано. Хорошо бы услышать и другие мнения наших участников.

Comment: @Sharon Чем вы докажете, что это именительный падеж, а не винительный?

Comment: @Sharon Молока вам не будет дано = часть целого, родительный падеж, трансформируем в утверждение. Вам дано молоко.

Comment: @Sharon Конечно, к "дано" вполне успешно можно подставить существительное ( дано условие = есть условие), в отличие от "накурено". По этой логике должно быть двусоставное.

Answer (score 3):

Предложения такого вида в лингвистике считаются **дискуссионными**.

Фактически это **отдельный вид безличных предложений** с характерными чертами: (1) **семантика** наличия или отсутствия; (2) **отрицание НЕ**; (3) соотносительное **двусоставное утвердительное** предложение; (4) **сущ. в форме Р.п**. как обязательный структурный элемент (семантический субъект сказуемого). (5) Форма Р.п. **в начале** предложения как его актуализация.

Сюда относятся предложения со словом **«нет»**: есть время (двусоставное ) — нет времени (односоставное).

В заданном предложении использовано **местоимение «ничего»** в форме Р.п.  (семантический субъект действия в начале предложения): *Это дано. Это будет дано. Что дано? Что еще будет дано.* Переходим к отрицанию: ***Ничего не будет дано.***

И делаем вывод. Это **односоставное безличное** отрицательное предложение **особой структуры**: местоимение «ничего» (семантический субъект действия в форме Р.п.) в роли дополнения + составное именное сказуемое «не будет дано».

Соотносительное утвердительное предложение является **двусоставным**: *Что будет дано? Ничего не будет дано.*

При замене местоимения **существительным**: *Условие дано/условие есть. Условие не будет дано/условия нет.*

**Вывод.** Самые простые с виду предложения могут быть **сложными** по грамматике. Вот, например, диалог:

Условие задано? (Двусоставное.) — Условие не задано. Двусоставное.) — А что задано? (Двусоставное.) — Ничего не задано.(Односоставное.) Нет никаких условий.(Односоставное.)

Comment: _«**Предложения такого вида в лингвистике считаются дискуссионными.**»_ ===  Сказав это, наверное, следовало бы и пояснить, почему приведённое в вопросе предложение считается дискуссионным. У Вас же в ответе НИЧЕГО по этому поводу нет – просто повторён другими словами данный ранее ответ Ajgy.

Comment: Очень рада за Ajgy, если вы считаете его ответ исчерпывающим. Я же считаю, что добавила нужные сведения, причем строго по грамматической классификации.  Предложение , которое вы цитируете, не мое. Эту фразу я взяла из учебника, и это тоже было вступлением к последующему изложению материала. Спасибо за внимание  и до свидания.

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнение к первому ответу**

Дополнительная информация для участника @Cлава, который не увидел ничего нового в моем ответе.

Действительно, данное предложение считает безличным автор вопроса, такое же мнение обозначено и в первом ответе. Но вот объяснения у всех разные. Это предложение **выглядит безличным**, и носители языка интуитивно чувствуют это. Вот только структура  вносит сомнение: в **позиции подлежащего** находится отрицательное местоимение  в форме Р.п. Да еще сравнить можно с утвердительной формой: *Что будет дано? Ничего не будет дано.*

Предложения такой структуры **часто встречаются** в языке, поэтому их лучше видеть заранее и знать, как они построены. Да, утвердительная и отрицательная формы составляют **парный вариант**. И главное, мы видим влияние **частицы НЕ**, с которой хорошо знакомы по теме дополнений с отрицанием. И вот здесь частица НЕ не просто меняет падеж, а **вмешивается в структуру предложения**, превращая двусоставное утвердительное предложение в односоставное отрицательное предложение.

Познакомившись подробно с такими предложениями, мы в дальнейшем легко **узнаем** их в тексте. Это односоставные безличные отрицательные предложения **особой структуры**, которую я обозначила в ответе.